# VueJS: setup() hook inside an OptionAPI component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuejs3

Hello everyone and thanks in advance for your help.

I am new to VueJS and was asked to work with a big codebase that uses the OptionAPI of VueJS. This code was written before Vue3 was release. However, it seems like the programmers of this had been already using features of the CompositionAPI such as the `setup()` hook alongside with the `data()` method to declare the state.

My problem is, I can't understand the difference between the `setup()` hook and the `data()` function in terms of functionalities provided to the component. In many places of this code base, components use both functions to declare their properties / functions that will be used in the code.

What is the difference between declaring a property inside `data()` and one inside `setup()` ? Is it simply the sign of bad programming practice, or could it have been done for a specific reason ?

For instance, here is the most naive example. In this case, is there any reason why using the `setup()` method ?

```js
<script>
import { ref  } from'vue'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },
    setup() {
        const tmp = ref(0)
        // expose to template and other options API hooks
        return {
            tmp
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.count) // 0
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <div>
            Control with Option API: <button @click="count++">{{ count  }} and {{tmp}}</button>
            <p></p>
            Control with Composition API: <button @click="tmp++">{{ count  }} and {{tmp}}</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: Both ways are ok. I would commonly not suggest to mix Options API with Compositions API, but it's not a sign of bad programming practice, when someone do this. It could be the step in the migration from Options API to Compositions API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both `data` and `setup` as used in a component, the most likely reason for that may be that `setup` acts like a modern alternative for `mixins`:

[playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNplksFugzAMhl/F4jLaVWW9VlBt6mmHvQEXFowaFRwUnKoS4t3nJNCijktsbP/+YmdMvvp+f3OYHJOcsevbivFUEkBe61swxPx1zIbgU7VaXYsy0aTKZA4CjCMo44hhmub8LBacYOuDrDuUGBTe6a2pnVpy8yx2ybNVb3EHZXXPYuuuN5ZhhBobTXg24hMS78BiAxM01nTwJvxvvq5xpFgLqRvw3Bp1/dF3TekGRt9MGRo40hS+PP3Y+N8D8jcx2lvVppJanELKXlyH8F7AIWRZZGdJQOJtSgr8JeE9AApe5dpwrjHT0BjqiquFwn+LWBjbEQ5xbtMuHMLj+nV25F46C/vL7V5VH4hPTSVAjrE+PlWXTfhOcyVf9LCPq9xG579Sh3wx9fAUkrfgJVa1fmZzjYxJ8PLssc9k+gNtG88j)

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="inc">
      {{ count }}
    </button> * {{ time }} = {{ product }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

function useClockMixin() {
  const time = ref(0)
  setInterval(() => time.value += 1)
  return { time }
}
  
export default defineComponent({
   data() {
      return {count: 1}
   },
   setup() {
      const { time } = useClockMixin()
      return { time }
   },
   computed: {
       product() {return this.count * this.time }
   },
   methods: {
     inc() {this.count += 1}
   }
})
</script>
```

Old mixins have many problems with type support, overlapping, and other unexpected things. Using composition-style mixins in `setup` is much more clear way to express what you want, get better typings, and provide better code quality all at once.

---

Data and Setup don't really have differences other than:

- Setup can be `async` (must be used with `<Suspense>`)
- Setup may return a render function

And that's it (comment if I've missed something important)

Answer (score 1):

maybe they want to emphasize data . the difference is that anything `data()` returns will be reacted while `setup()` is a general purpose pattern it can return anything (methods, data, mixins, components...)

basically your example is equivalent it's just a matter of whether you like it or not